# Get longest and shortest string in a esthetical way

Tags: c#

I have the following lines in my code. They are taking more place than they should. Any suggestions for a smaller code.

```
string longestString;
string shortestString;
if (string1.Length > string2.Length) 
{
   longestString = string1;
   shortestString = string2;
}
else 
{
   longestString = string2;
   shortestString = string1;
}
```

I know, not a really important question, but this is taking 2/3 of the entire method and not the important stuff.

Comment: `longString = string1.Length > string2.Length ? string1 : string2;`

Comment: that is the right way to do it. Some things can't be really aesthetical

Comment: Absolutely not effective, but just for fun: `var lst = new[] { string1, string2 }.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToList();            
            string shortestString = lst[0];
            string longestString = lst[1];`

Comment: It's kinda odd how these questions suddenly receive so much attention. It's not even a proper StackOverflow question! The code works and optimization is not an issue, meaning this actually belongs to CodeReview.

Comment: @DionV. In its current state, it would be closed as off-topic hypothetical/example code on Code Review. CR requires real code and as much context as possible. Who knows why OP needs to do this? Could be an X-Y thing.

Comment: @Mat'sMug alright, fair enough, but I'd still argue if it is fit for SO. As you asked in your comment; Who knows why OP needs to do this? The OP states there is no problem with the code, nor with the program, nor with the performance. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't SO a place where we should provide real problems?

Comment: I'm not saying it's on-topic for SO, just that it would be off-topic for Code Review without more context provided. :-)

Comment: Your code is fine. The lines are short, clear and the structure is expandable. Which is more than I would say about most answers.

Comment: Kotlin: `val (short, long) = listOf(string1, string2).sortBy { it.length }`

Comment: It might indeed be an opinion based question. Nevertheless it gave me some ideas and insights that might increased the quality of my code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
int diff = string1.Length.CompareTo(string2.Length);
string longestString  = diff > 0 ? string1 : string2;
string shortestString = diff > 0 ? string2 : string1;
```

But if you have more than these two strings and you want a general solution you could use:

```
var lenLookup = new[] { string1, string2 }.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToList();
string shortestString = lenLookup.First();
string longestString = lenLookup.Last();
```

Comment: Interesting (and very correct in the most general case) that you chose to cache the "real" comparison, instead of redoing it twice :-) In this way, the number of accesses to `string1` and `string2` is the same as in the original code... so it is "more equivalent".

Comment: Or equivalent: `bool s1bigger = string1.Length > string2.Length; string logestString = s1bigger ? string1 : string2; ...`

Comment: Well, since it turned out that I also needed to 'pre-process' the string. I actually used this one. var cleaned = new[] { original, modified }
                .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, "[^a-zA-Z]", "").ToLower())
                .OrderBy(s => s.Length);
            var shortest = cleaned.First();
            var longest = cleaned.Last();

Answer (score 11):

Since your code would always perform either the if or else path, pick one as "default" and merge it with variable declaration:

```
string longestString = string2
string shortestString = string1;
if (string1.Length > string2.Length) 
{
   longestString = string1;
   shortestString = string2;
}
```

Bonus points for the fact that you'll actually *initialize* those variables.

Comment: With the caveat that this works well if `string1` and `string2` don't cause side-effects when getted.

Comment: Re-reading the OP i'm positive this wouldn't introduce any *additional* side effect (original code would also always get both strings)

Comment: Yep... This is just putting the dot on the *i* and the dash on the *t*... i.e. being pedantic.

Comment: @xanatos If a getter is causing side effects, then you have a much bigger problem...

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could do this to clear your method up;

```
public string GetLongestString(string str1, string str2)
{
    return str1.Length > str2.Length ? str1 : str2;
}

public string GetShortestString(string str1, string str2)
{
    return str1.Length > str2.Length ? str2 : str1;
}

string longestString = GetLongestString(string1, string2);
string shortestString = GetShortestString(string1, string2);
```

And reuse it whenever you want!

Heck, make it even cooler (in co-op mode with Tim);

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLongestStrings(params string[] strings)
{
    //returns first string with largest length out of given argumenst
    int maxSize = strings.Max(str => str.Length);
    return strings.Where(s => s.Length == maxSize);
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetShortestStrings(params string[] strings)
{
    //returns first string with shortest length out of given arguments
    int minSize = strings.Min(str => str.Length);
    return strings.Where(s => s.Length == minSize);
}
```

Usage;

```
string longestString = GetLongestStrings("str1", "str2", /*...*/ "strN").FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT1: My first implementation is not the most efficient. As Tim suggested;

```
public string GetLongestString(params string[] strings)
{
    return strings.OrderBy(s => s.Length).First();
}

public string GetShortestString(params string[] strings)
{
    return strings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
}
```

Usage;

```
string longestString = GetLongestString("str1", "str2", /*...*/ "strN");
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Comment: But this enumerates the strings twice. Once to determine the min-/max-length and once to find the string with that length. You could simply use `strings.OrderBy(s => s.Length).First()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter indeed. `OrderBy` would be a better option, but since you provided that in your answer, I'm not going to take credit for it.

Comment: @DionV.; however, the `params` approach is  nice. Since it's possible that there are multiple strings with the same min/max-length you could improve it by returning an `IEnumerable<String>`, so `strings.Where(s => s.Length == minSize)`. Then the caller can decide what he wants to do with it, if he uses `GetShortestString(..).FirstOrDefault()` or `string.Join(",",  GetShortestString(..))`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's an even neater approach! I'd argue that it does depend a bit on what the OP needs though. If it's only the first longest string he needs, I'd suggest he just keeps it simple. But still, returning the enumerable fits more needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "? :" operator

```
string longestString = string1.Length > string2.Length ? string1 : string2;
string shortestString = string1.Length > string2.Length ? string2 : string1;
```

Comment: @xanatos please look more carefully at the second part of the statement: "string2 : string1"